# String#count multiple parameters intersection explanation

Tags: ruby

I'm going through the Ruby Docs and I do not fully understand how the String#count method works. According to the documentation if multiple arguments are provided an intersection of those are used to select. I do not fully understand how that works. Can someone provide a more through explanation?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so in the examples, `count('lo')` counts all the characters that are either `l` or `o`, and `count('lo', 'o')` counts all the characters that are "either `l` or `o`" *and* "is `o`", that is, it's the same as `count('o')`.

In the third example, `count('hello', '^l')` means count characters that are "either `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, or `o`" *and* "not `l`", that is, it's the same as `count('heo')`.

The intersection property is especially useful when used with complementary ranges. For example, `count('j-t', '^lp')` counts all the letters that are between `j` and `t`, except for `l` and `p`.